# How to fix '"CheckAttributes" task could not be loaded'-error after installing Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013, updates

After installing Update 4, I now find myself unable to build (or even clean) any solution. I keep getting:

> Error 1   The "CheckPathAttributes" task could not be loaded from the
>   assembly C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  HandlePageNotFound

Does anyone know how to resolve this please?

Comment: Well, you're probably better off than I am: https://plus.google.com/102054487224209127233/posts/NS1vAN6apPf - thanks for posting this, now to try the suggestions below. BTW - on  Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1029189/after-update-4-has-been-installed-such-packages-are-failed-to-load

Comment: Oh my. I see this question **immediately after** updating VS2013 to update 4!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found the solution via this

[TransformXml task could not be loaded from Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358747/transformxml-task-web-publishing-tasks-dll-error)

In my case, I had Visual Studio 2012 installed on an E: drive already, so I found a copy of `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks` in

`E:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web`

So I copied that file, and `Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform` to here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web`

and now all is well :)

Comment: Copying the DLL files from C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web to C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Same as above from v10.0 (I did not have a web folder for v11.0) to v12.0 and it worked as well.

Comment: Did not help me, unfortuneately

Comment: @JTIM Did any of the other answers help? My answer specifically helped me, but it may not help other people.

Comment: @JasonEvans I am trying rebuild, all other did not work. Crossing my fingers :D

Comment: I copied the file did not work. But When I uninstalled  "Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013", and repaired the VS2013, then the issue was gone.

Answer (score 24):

Well, here's "my solution".

First the horrific "prompt of death" (plus the same "licensing issue" annoyance) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26904068/304683):

[image: VS 2013 update 4 issues]

What I've attempted (and result) based on info from the interwebs:

1. Close VS 2013 and *rename* the folder:

   `C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache` 

   **Result**: No effect/errors persist (VS will re-create that folder on startup)
2. Rerun the Visual Studio Update 4 installer and `Repair`

   **Result**: Successfully "fixed" whatever it was.

   This will take about an hour which is slower than when I originally installed the update so that was a clue, or rather, more like "well, I hope that means it found what it did wrong or forgot/missed out on" (and not, "oh crap, now I'm really screwing things up even more")

A quick summary of my environment so that hopefully will guide you to your solution:

- I did install `Office Developer Tools Nov 2014` prior to the Update so in my case, that wasn't the issue (I did not remove/uninstall)
- I have `Resharper`, and I did not disable it, so this too doesn't seem related (some have pointed this out)
- I did update to `Web Essentials 2013 for Update 4` after the initial Update (it will prompt you to after installing VS Update 4). I didn't do anything after the `Repair` (didn't remove/re-install/etc Web Essentials after the `Repair`).
- I have VS 2012 as well, just mentioning this though that was never affected in any way (and was my fallback while this issue was stopping me from using VS2013)

Hth...

Comment: Awesome, thanks for sharing that info. I've encountered these warnings also, but in typical cavalier style, I just ignored them and hoped for the best :) So far, it does not look like I'm suffering, however your advice will come in handy if that situation changes.

Comment: @JasonEvans - in my case, I couldn't ignore...couldn't (re)build existing projects with myriad errors too many to list- it gets to the nosebleed level :) So I "had to" figure something out (or keep using VS 2012). Rock and a hard place :) Best~

Comment: Repairing Update 4 fixed the problem for me

Comment: I did a repair on my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate which fixed it (although it does take a long time)

Answer (score 10):

Uninstalling "Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 – November 2014 Update" helped me. Now all works as before.

Comment: Hmmm, I did install that thinking about it. Maybe that was at fault, rather than Update 4.

Comment: Same for me, I blamed Update 4 too. Uninstalling this fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes, it was Office dev tools update that for some reason deleted "c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll".

Comment: This worked for me... Thanks! It's a very long uninstall by the way, no need to be alarmed. :)

Answer (score 8):

If you have VS 2012 installed on your machine. Copy **Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll and Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets** from C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\web\ into C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web (the path for VS 2013). Restart visual studio.

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't copy the file `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets`, maybe I should do that just in case.

Answer (score 3):

I have only VS2013 (now with Update 4) and I solve this problem as follows: Close VS, copy "**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.Dll**" into the "**C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web**" directory and start VS (folder **v11.0** no contains **Web** subfolder). Now I can rebuild website projects without any error again.

Answer (score 2):

My problem cleared thanks to the same [TransformXml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358747/transformxml-task-web-publishing-tasks-dll-error) link and the suggestion to install [Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8279)

Comment: Here is a link to the SDK Downloads: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Copying **"Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"** and **"Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform.dll"** from **"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web"** to **"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web"** also works