# Disable "Get a developer license" notification in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I just updated my VS2013 to Update 4. Now there's this really annoying red flag in the top right corner of VS that wants me to get a license to develop Windows Store and Windows Phone apps. I really don't want to create these kinds of applications.

How do I turn the message off? Getting a license by registering with an account and sending some more personal data to Microsoft is really not an option. And "Dismiss" seems to just mute it for some time...

Comment: **[There is a patch available to fix the issue](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44998)** ([From the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26948802/107625)).

Answer (score 10):

As [David Kolar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933660/disable-get-a-developer-license-notification-in-visual-studio-2013-update-4#comment42419079_26933660) say, this question is a duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 - How to Stop Annoying Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26904068/4182246).

Quoting the [solution that works for me (since m a ReSharper user)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26948802/4182246):

> 1. Make sure the critical notification is currently active (i.e., red notification).
> 2. Open up File Explorer and navigate to the C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Notifications
>      directory.
> 3. Open the Notifications_Active.xml file found in in a text editor.
> 4. Find the notification element referring to the developer license.
> 5. Change the value of the Severity element to 0 instead of 2.
>
> This should make the red alert no longer kick in for this notification
>   as long as you leave the notification active (i.e., do not dismiss
>   it).

Just a note: before continuing with step 2 remember to close all instances of visual studio, otherwise changes to the severity in the *Notifications_Active.xml* file won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the severity didn't work for me. Instead, I opened VS2013, dismissed the alert, then inside Notifications_Archive.xml, I changed the expiration to some time in the past. I closed and reopened VS2013 and the alert is now gone.